# id attribut is missing in yii2 radio button

Tags: yii2

I'm facing one problem in yii2 radio buttons while using with yii2 dynamic forms package. yii2 is not generating the radio button with id attribute. Due to missing of id attributes in radio buttons, yii2 dynamic forms radio buttons values are always setting as 1. So Please help me how to overcome this problem.

**Edited**

```
<?= $form->field($client_allow_acces, "[$i]access_type")->radioList([1 => 'Allow access', 2 => 'Can\'t allow access'], ['uncheckValue' => null, 'id'=>'custom_id_value']) ?>
```

I'm getting the html output below

```
<div class="form-group field-clientallowaccess-0-access_type required">
    <label class="control-label" for="custom_id_value">Access Type</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="ClientAllowAccess[0][access_type]" value="">
    <div id="custom_id_value">
        <label><input type="radio" name="ClientAllowAccess[0][access_type]" value="1"> Allow access</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="ClientAllowAccess[0][access_type]" value="2"> Can't allow access</label>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block"></div>
</div>
```

My custom id value is coming in div element. but I need it in radio button itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your related code....

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for reply. I edited my question. Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use following code because of your given id is assigned to `div` in your code. that is on `<div id="custom_id_value">`.

```
<?= $form->field($client_allow_acces, '[$i]access_type')->radioList([1 => 'Allow access', 2 => 'Can\'t allow access'],[ 'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
                                    $return = '<label class="modal-radio">';
                                    $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" id="custom_id_value_'.$index.'" >';
                                    $return .= '<span>  ' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                                    $return .= '</label>';
                                    return $return;
                             }]); ?>
```